# How to find certain arrays inside an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of arrays.
Example:

```
[
 [a, b, c],
 [b, d],
 [a, c],
 [b],
 [a, b, c, d]
]
```

In practice, inner arrays will be relatively short, but the outer array will be a few thousand rows.

Now, I have a reference array.
Example:

```
[a, b, c]
```

The challenge is to determine which rows of the first array are completely contained in the reference array.  For this example, I would want rows 1, 3, and 4 returned to me after this check.

I can do this using a nested loop pretty easily, but I was wondering if there was a clever algorithm that would be more scalable.

Recap: I need the row numbers that are some subset of the reference array.  Row elements are not necessarily unique.
EDIT:  There are about 200 unique elements that can be inside each array. The array of arrays will be constant, but I will need to perform this same search for many different reference arrays

Comment: Are you going to check for the same collection of arrays more than once? Otherwise - whatever you do, you are going to have to read all the data.

Comment: The reference array is going to change fairly frequently.  The array of arrays can be assumed to stay constant

Comment: OK, you should add it to the question - this is very important. Also: What is the 'universe' size? How many elements are in the 'universe' (can be in any array)?

Comment: Good point.  The 'universe' is somewhere between 100 and 200 unique elements.

Comment: If additional data structure is allowed, I recommend to create a hashtable - of course, it elements of inner arrays are quite simple (not objects or something else which would be difficult to index). You may index with array length and it's string representation (delimited, may be, with something). Thus lookup will first check length (very cheap) and from found elements with matched length - compare as strings (cheap too). But it's near duplicate of original array. However, search will be near `O(1)` time

Comment: Additional structure is definitely allowed, though I'm not sure I follow your solution.  For this to work, I would need to do a hash lookup on the set of all subsets of my reference array?

Comment: You might also consider posting this in codegolf.stackexchange.com, I beleive this is the kind of challenge they like. ;)

Comment: Are the elements within each row and within the reference array sorted?  Does the order of the elements within an array matter?

Comment: @pentadecagon: we can assume that the elements in each row are sorted.  Since these rows are relatively small (average of about 10 elements) even if they were unsorted, putting the elements in order before doing any other work would add a negligible amount of overhead.

Comment: @msb: thanks for the reference.  Hadn't been to codegolf before.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your reference array as a structure where you can check for membership of an element in O(1) time (e.g., using a hash table or just a 0/1 membership indicator array since the universe is small), then you can store your collection of arrays as a trie where each array is sorted, and traverse the trie finding paths to leaves that are completely contained in your reference array. This can reduce complexity because you'll be traversing simultaneously for a subcollection of arrays using single comparisons higher up in the trie when the arrays in your subcollection overlap, and you'll be skipping subsets of arrays simultaneously when they contain a common element that is not in your reference array.

Comment: I like this answer.  Requires me to traverse the array of arrays once (no way around that), and then every lookup afterwards depends on the length of the reference array.  From a computational point of view, I think this as efficient as possible?

Comment: @cnick It's very hard to prove lower bounds on the complexity of solving problems, but yes I think this is close or equal to optimal especially if you have large overlaps in your collection of arrays. I think you definitely need Omega(S) time where S is the number of arrays you have in your set. If the sets overlap a lot, you get close to that bound with this trie approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this operation several times for the same array of arrays, and the inner arrays besides being short have a non-extensive set of possible elements, and they never have repeat elements (thanks @Kunukn), you can create an alternate structure turning your inner arrays into numbers and doing a "XOR" and "OR" between the element to be found and the array. That way, you'll loop your array only once. What's more, you may sort your array of arrays by value, which might be useful for other purposes.
Example: a is 1, b is 2, c is 4, d is 8. Your sample array of arrays become:

```
[
 [a, b, c], // 1 + 2 + 4 == 7
 [b, d], // 2 + 8 == 10
 [a, c], // 1 + 4 == 5
 [b], // 2 == 2
 [a, b, c, d] // 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 == 15
]
```

Then, your reference array `[a, b, c]` is calculated into 7, the same way as the 1st element in the above array of arrays. Now, to search the element. Assuming a 4-bit integer to represent them, you'd have:

```
7 XOR 7 => 1110 XOR 1110 == 0000; 0000 OR 1110 == 1110 => equal to 7, found
10 XOR 7 => 0101 XOR 1110 == 1011; 1011 OR 1110 == 1111 => not equal to 7, not found
5 XOR 7 => 1010 XOR 1110 == 0100; 0100 OR 1110 == 1110 => equal to 7, found
2 XOR 7 => 0100 XOR 1110 == 1010; 1010 OR 1110 == 1110 => equal to 7, found
15 XOR 7 => 1111 XOR 1110 == 0001; 0001 OR 1110 == 1111 => not equal to 7, not found
```

EDIT: even though you won't have an integer that uses 200 bits, you can still use a 200-bit structure and do the same operations, it will just be a bit more of work for you.

Comment: I think this would only work if the array elements are distinct, e.g. inner item being `[a, a], //1+1==2` and a reference array being `[b], //2==2` would make it false positive match. For distinct items I think this is a good approach imho.

Comment: Thanks. It's true, they can't repeat, I assumed it was the case without asking OP about it. <:-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use subset matching.
I assume your dataset are sorted.

Build the subset possibilities from the reference array. Best if the reference array is small, else the dataset to be build and compared would be to big.

E.g. the sorted subset matching of the reference array `[a, b, c]` gives

```
[a], [b], [c], [a,b], [a,c], [b,c], [a,b,c]
```

From the dataset

```
[
 [a, b, c],
 [b, d],
 [a, c],
 [a, c],
 [b],
 [a, b, c, d]
]
```

Build a hash table of the data with their position in an array

```
 hash table
 "abc", [1]
 "bd", [2]
 "ac", [3,4]
 "b", [5]
 "abcd", [6]
```

reference array hash

```
hashReference = {"a","b","c","ab", "ac," "bc", "abc"}
```

Algorithm

```
foreach key in hashRefence 
    lookup the hash table
```

This returns `[5], [3,4], [1]`